# Last page with UIPageViewController

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

How do you get the total number of pages (or the last page) when working with UIPageViewController in swift?
Obviously assuming you do not know how many pages will be displayed.
I have an app similar to iBooks and I need to display at the bottom of each page "Page1 of x".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by adding a simple property (like pageId or pageNumber) to the ViewController class that I was displaying inside the UIPageViewController.

By instantiation I added an incremented NSUInteger value to the ViewController. As result every ViewController had a property with its own ascending page number.

This page number can be used and accessed directly for displaying it in a label or you can also create a delegate method that is called when the view appears and pass the value to another class.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to include the current page number, what is still puzzling me is how to know the total page number since the very beginning. I thought I had found a solution but it is very buggy and I need to chang wit over again now.